# Split rows in Pandas into multiple rows based on a semicolon, but the change appears only in one column and not in others

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form:

### Sl No.     |     description1   |      description2

```
1              dog;lion;tiger         sentence1
2              cat;pet;elephant       sentence2
```

I want the output like this:

### Sl No.     |     description1   |  description2

```
1              dog             sentence1
               lion
               tiger

2              cat             sentence2
               pet
               elephant
```

I tried the explode function but it did not give me the desired result.

Comment: def jsonify(x):
    list1 = list(x.split(";"))
    #a = x.split(";", 1)[0]
    return list1


df['descrip']=df['description1'].apply(jsonify)

Comment: df = df.explode('descrip')